# Expected identifier and ARC problems when re-using code

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I copied some classes from an older project into my new project. I had to remove all `release/autorelease` statements but I still have some errors:

```
 NSArray *allContacts = [(__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)];
    for (int i =0; i < allContacts.count; i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = [allContacts objectAtIndex:i];
```

In the first line I get `Expected identifier`. In the third line I get `implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'ABRecordRef (aka 'cpmnst void *)' is disallowed with ARC`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Well, you've got a pretty blatant syntax error on the first line. What have you tried to do about the second one?

Comment: ok fixed the first one...but the I dont know how to fix the second error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider:

```
NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

A function whose name contains `Copy` returns a reference that’s owned by the caller, which means that the caller must release it. Under ARC, releasing is automatic but you need to tell ARC that the reference returned by that function is owned by the caller because the function declaration lacks that information. This is an example of ownership transfer and you should use `__bridge_transfer` in this case:

```
NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

In:

```
ABRecordRef person = [allContacts objectAtIndex:i];
```

`-objectAtIndex:` returns an object that is not owned by the caller. Since you’re assigning that object to a non-object type (`ABRecordRef`), you need a simple bridge cast:

```
ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[allContacts objectAtIndex:i];
```